# How to Acess Billing Adress of Account Object in Vf Page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

This is a basic question i am exploring myself please help me out in this. I could not access the "billing  address" and "shipping address" feilds in Account (standard object).
This is the error **Error Error: Could not resolve field 'Billing Address' from  value binding '{!Account.Billing Address}' in page AssignmentPage** i am getting. How resolve it

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="System Details" collapsible="false" columns="2" >
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.Billing Address}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it as "Billing City", etc.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingStreet}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingCity}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a formula field addressing all the Billing related fields and then access that on the VF (as long as it is read-only)